# How to estimate the iteration time and display it with tqdm of a for loop?

Tags: python, time, python-itertools, tqdm

I want to estimate the duration of the iterations of the following code and display it on a progress bar (tdqm). This function will give all the possible combinations of the `string.printable`.

---

```py
import strings
from itertools import combinations

def generate_combinations(iterable):
  lst = list(iterable)
  for lenght in range(0, len(lst) + 1):
    for i in combinations(lst, lenght):
      with open('passwords.txt', 'a') as f:
        w = ''.join(map(str, i))
        f.write(w + '\n')

generate_combinations(string.printable)
```

---

I think you can do this using `time` and `tqdm`.

**Expected output:**

```
estimated time: 12 seconds left
tqdm progress bar: 12% |||||||...
```

Comment: Didn't know about [tqdm] before seeing this.  Looks like a neat module.  The docs have [an example that uses nested iterators](https://github.com/tqdm/tqdm#nested-progress-bars) that may work for you.  As a brute force approach you could try `trange` instead of `range` and `tqdm(combinations(...))`.  You could also put your two for loops into a single generator and iterate over it.

Comment: this is a pretty close answer to what I was looking for. Didin't notice the nested iterators in the tqdm docs, before you told me. Thank you.

Comment: @jq170727 can you show me how to put two for loops into a single generator? I think I didn't get what you mean.

Comment: Instead of two loops you have a single `for (lenght, i) in combined(lst):` where combined is something like `def combined(lst):\n  for lenght in range(0, len(lst) + 1):\n    for i in combinations(lst, lenght):\n      yield (lenght, i)\n` (note you need proper indentation and newlines should be `\n` appears).

Comment: @jq170727 I updated the answer with your suggestion, it improved a lot!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The final answer (with the suggestion by @jq170727) is the following code:

---

```py
import string
from tqdm.auto import trange, tqdm
from itertools import permutations
```

The requested generator (on google colab, using TPU: around 10k it / s)

```py
def combined(lst, lenStart, lenEnd):
  for i in trange(lenStart, lenEnd + 1, desc='Progress'):
    for subset in tqdm(permutations(lst, i),  desc='Subsets', leave = False):
      w = ''.join(map(str, subset))
      yield w
```

---

And here we got the same generator with better efficiency (on google colab, using TPU: around 950k / s)

```py
def compress_permutation(lst, lenStart, lenEnd):
  yield ','.join([''.join(map(str, subset)) for i in trange(lenStart, lenEnd + 1, desc='Progress') for subset in tqdm(permutations(lst, i), desc='Subsets', leave = False)])
```

```py
iterable = list(string.printable[:94])
lenStart, lendEnd = 1, 9

for subset in compress_permutation(iterable, l1, l2):
  with open('passwords.txt', 'a') as f:
    f.write(subset)
```